# Can I get windows 10 running better on my system?

Tags: windows-10

After I installed Windows 10 on my PC [2.4GHz x64 CPU, 2GB RAM] via an install USB created with UltraISO, I have some issues:

- One minute after opening Chrome, my PC works slowly
- Watching video lessons or using VS Code causes my PC to work very slowly

Can I find the source of my performance issues and get my system running faster, or did I make a mistake with my installation? (I want to use PyCharm and VSCode.)

Comment: What are the specifications of the machine? How much RAM do you have? Which CPU? Do you have sufficient storage space remaining?

Comment: Its really hard to tell, but 2gb is pretty close to minimum spec. Also worth mentioning what the exact processor is (since with modern processors, processor speed means little) and whether you're using a hard drive or SSD. Chances are performance issues might be hardware related, especially with a fresh install

Comment: No, Windows will never run okay with 2GB of RAM - you'll have extreme lag with whatever you do. If running 4GB or less of RAM and/or a quad-core or less CPU, Linux would be the recommended route (say [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/)), as Windows is, and has always been, resource-hungry due to the number of services it runs by default _(Chromium-based browsers consume ~1GB of RAM, with Chrome being notorious for using more than that)_. If needing to run Windows-only programs on Linux, [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) can be used, with both PyCharm and VS Code being cross-platform.

Comment: As you have a limited RAM, we could close third party thread to run in Windows 10, we could check that behavior in Clean Boot environment https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows, but if it persists almost similar in Clean Boot or if those third party software is necessary to you, you need to upgrade your hardware to get Windows 10 running well.

Answer (score 4):

Your PC is too low-spec. The software you want to use (Chrome, VS Code, PyCharm) cannot work with 2 GB of RAM. Not on Linux and most certainly not on Windows. PyCharm requires a *minimum* of 4 GB of *free* RAM.

Additionally, your CPU is probably way too slow. Without an exact make and model it’s hard to tell but I guess it’s a two-core CPU without Hyperthreading. That just won’t cut it today.

Your PC is probably too old to upgrade, too.

However, not all is lost. Instead of Windows, you should use a lightweight Linux distribution like Lubuntu or Xubuntu. This will free up a *tremendous* amount of RAM. You should use a web browser that is more memory efficient (Firefox or Midori or whatever). You should use an advanced text editor instead of an IDE (e.g. Sublime Text). You should not use Electron-based software (like VS Code).

Of course, this means things won’t be as comfortable, but the increased performance should more than make up for it.